# Model::create() throws exception when using multiple database connections

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

What is the correct way to use Eloquent with multiple databases to insert a new record.

The reason there are multiple databases is because a limited quantity of user's data resides on each shard. Upon authentication their shard is looked up in a directory, and all further queries are made on their shard.

When running:

`$user = User::on('user-shard1')->create(array('name' => 'John'));`

The following exception is thrown:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::create()`

Are we implementing Eloquent the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `on` for this, for `create` is a static method on the `Model`, while `on` returns the `Eloquent\Builder`.

So instead do this:

```
$user = new User;
$user->setConnection('user-shard1');
$user->fill(array(..));
$user->save();
```

Comment: Looks like it's always using my default connection.

Comment: You're right, `create` instantiates new object with default connection. Use `fill` and `save` instead.

Comment: However I was able to use DB::connection('user-shard1')->table('users')->insert($data);

Comment: Yes, however this has nothing to do with `Eloquent`. So eg. no timestamps automatically added, no event fired etc